ESS Eval Region/Load file/Eval Function button not showing on starting an R file
I am on Debian 12  / Ubuntu 22.
I installed emacs+ess by doing
sudo apt install emacs
sudo apt install ess
When I start an R file, it does not show me the icons for instance for Load file.
Can someone please point me in the right direction? What can I do to fix this?
Here is a screen shot:

On Debian 10, my ESS menu bar looked like this :


What is the value of ess-use-toolbar?

Can you try M-x load-library <RET> ess-toolbar <RET>?

M-x load-library <RET> ess-toolbar <RET> did not bring back the buttons.

Please do M-x customize-option <RET> ess-use-toolbar <RET>. What does the customization buffer for ess-use-toolbar show? Is it switched on or off?

When I do M-x customize-option <RET> it prompts for Customize variable. When I type in ess-use-toobar and press <RET> it says [No match].

Probably because you misspelled the name: ess-use-toobar instead of ess-use-toolbar...

To get this
ESS-specific Toolbar Icons in Toolbar

do this

;; Recipe for `emacs -Q`

(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
(package-initialize)

(use-package ess-toolbar
  :autoload ess-add-toolbar)

(use-package ess-r-mode
  :custom
  (ess-use-toolbar t)
  (ess-toolbar-global nil)
  :config
  (add-hook 'inferior-ess-r-mode-hook
            (defun my-inferior-ess-r-mode-hook-20240405113534003 ()
              (menu-bar-showhide-tool-bar-menu-customize-enable-top)
              (ess-add-toolbar))
            t))



Dear mxnt, many thanks for your reply. I pasted all except the first 2 lines of the lisp code in my .emacs. Now I can see the buttons which were missing.

I have a small related query. Why do I need to do this manually as of now? If I remember correctly, in the earlier versions of Debian the buttons would show up on their own.
